# Avoid cross-origin policy via Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, same-origin-policy

Site A is a website with an `<iframe>` containing Site B. This is running on a chrome browser with an extension.

I have control over the extension. What I would like to do is give the user controls to edit parts of Site B.

The following is invoked when a user presses a button on the extension. The intention is to load jQuery in so I can use it, target the iframe on the page, reach into the iframe then change its body color.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'assets/jquery.min.js'}, function () {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: "jQuery('iframe').contents().find('body').css('backgroundColor', 'red');"
  });
});
```

Site A and Site B are on different domains, so the same origin policy kicks in. It's also worth noting that Site B has not given cross origin access rights to Site A. I also am not the owner of Site A or Site B so cannot amend their cross origin policies.

My hope is that when running from the extension I have a little more consent from the user to be able to get around the same origin policy and perform the action above.

Comment: If you want to inject code into the site B frame that's perfectly doable. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Is the iframe's origin is same as site B?

Comment: @extempl the sites were one 2 different origins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your script to be injected into the frame you can use the `allFrames` option to inject the code in all the frames of the page.

Before running the code you'll have to check if you are inside A or B: you can do this by comparing `window.self` with `window.parent`. In the top frame (A) those will be the same object, but inside an `<iframe>` (like B) those will be different.

Here it is:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'assets/jquery.min.js', allFrames: true}, function () {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: "if (self != parent) jQuery('body').css('backgroundColor', 'red');",
        allFrames: true
    });
});
```

**NOTE**: since January 2021, for Manivest V3 use [`chrome.scripting.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript) instead.

The above code will be injected both into A and B, but will execute only in B. If multiple frames are in A, you'll also have to check if the frame is correct using for example `window.location.hostname`.